# Azure App Service Support Event Logger not showing real error, real error swallowed and showing some error about error pages instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, logging

I added a new view for a blog for my web application under my ASP.NET MVC App's Home directory, where the views are rendered through the HomeController.cs. I did update my HomeController.cs so that the new views are able to be loaded:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Blog()
{
 return View();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult PublicBetaLaunch()
{
return View();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult About()
{
 return View();
```

I was able to load the blog view in my local environment, but when I tried to do it on production, it didn't display the error which caused the blog not to load. Instead the following is logged in the App Service Support Event Logger. Does anyone know what is wrong and why it is showing this error related to error pages, rather than showing the real error? The real error seems to be swallowed by this, so we cannot debug and know what is the real problem. Initially it was redirecting to the custom error page we made, we turned that off through webconfig so it does not direct to custom error page anymore, but the event logger still does not show the real problem.

```
Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 3/1/2016 1:40:51 AM
Event time (UTC): 3/1/2016 1:40:51 AM
Event ID: 1037464643fc40148d0a4c9170a46dc5
Event sequence: 41
Event occurrence: 7
Event detail code: 0

Application information:
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/305978964/ROOT-2-131012691793709252
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /
Application Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\
Machine name: RD00155DC27294

Process information:
Process ID: 5520
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\TradeSumoQA

Exception information:
Exception type: InvalidOperationException
Exception message: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Home/Error.aspx ~/Views/Home/Error.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx ~/Views/Home/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Home/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Request information:
Request URL: http://qa.tradesumo.com/Home/Blog
Request path: /Home/Blog
User host address: 49.181.212.18
User: 
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type: 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\TradeSumoQA

Thread information:
Thread ID: 19
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\TradeSumoQA
Is impersonating: False
Stack trace: at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Custom event details:
```

Comment: can you remove the [AllowAnonymous] annotation and run it ?I know you need it,but still give a try.I suspect it is not able to find your view for some reason.

Comment: If I remove that, then wouldn't visitors who aren't logged in not be able to access the blog view at all?

Comment: yes,i want to figure out the issue.,wanna know if its because of authorization mechanism ?

Comment: I looked at my .csproject file, and I saw that I did not include the new view in that. Do I need to do that to render the page successfully in the browser?

Comment: Oh it works now! LOL!!